# Tag Synonym Request: [ppc] -> [powerpc]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tag wikis for [ppc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ppc) and [powerpc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/powerpc) are exactly the same. Please, make ppc a synonym for powerpc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone ahead and done this.